# yii user and rights- admin can not access any page

Tags: yii, controllers, rights

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Rights::t()
```

Getting this error when ever i want to go in any controller or in any controller's action. I am using yii user and rights. for instance when i type `localhost/business/address/create` i get the above error. 
Yii user is working fine, even rights too. But i cannot access any controller.

'bootstrap',
        'basePath'=>dirname(**FILE**).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
    'name'=>'My Web Application',

```
// preloading 'log' component
'preload'=>array('log'),

     'aliases' => array(
     'bootstrap' => 'ext.bootstrap' ),

// autoloading model and component classes
'import'=>array(
        //addedd these lines
        'application.modules.user.models.*',
    'application.modules.user.components.*',
        'application.modules.rights.*',
    'application.modules.rights.components.*',
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
             'bootstrap.behaviors.*',
            'bootstrap.helpers.*',
            'bootstrap.widgets.*'
),

'modules'=>array(
    // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

    'gii'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
        'password'=>'centangle',
                'generatorPaths' => array( 'bootstrap.gii',  ),

        // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
        'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
    ),
         'user'=>array(
            'tableUsers' => 'user',
            'tableProfiles' => 'profiles',
            'tableProfileFields' => 'profiles_fields',
              # encrypting method (php hash function)
            'hash' => 'md5',

            # send activation email
            'sendActivationMail' => true,

            # allow access for non-activated users
            'loginNotActiv' => false,

            # activate user on registration (only sendActivationMail = false)
            'activeAfterRegister' => false,

            # automatically login from registration
            'autoLogin' => true,

            # registration path
            'registrationUrl' => array('/user/registration'),

            # recovery password path
            'recoveryUrl' => array('/user/recovery'),

            # login form path
            'loginUrl' => array('/user/login'),

            # page after login
            'returnUrl' => array('/user/profile'),

            # page after logout
            'returnLogoutUrl' => array('/user/login'),
    ),
    'rights'=>array(
            'install'=>true,
        'superuserName'=>'admin', // Name of the role with super user privileges. 
           'authenticatedName'=>'Authenticated',  // Name of the authenticated user role. 
           'userIdColumn'=>'id', // Name of the user id column in the database. 
           'userNameColumn'=>'username',  // Name of the user name column in the database. 
           'enableBizRule'=>true,  // Whether to enable authorization item business rules. 
           'enableBizRuleData'=>true,   // Whether to enable data for business rules. 
           'displayDescription'=>true,  // Whether to use item description instead of name. 
           'flashSuccessKey'=>'RightsSuccess', // Key to use for setting success flash messages. 
           'flashErrorKey'=>'RightsError', // Key to use for setting error flash messages. 

           'baseUrl'=>'/rights', // Base URL for Rights. Change if module is nested. 
           'layout'=>'rights.views.layouts.main',  // Layout to use for displaying Rights. 
           'appLayout'=>'application.views.layouts.main', // Application layout. 
           'cssFile'=>'rights.css', // Style sheet file to use for Rights. 
           'install'=>false,  // Whether to enable installer. 
           'debug'=>false, 
    ),

),

// application components
'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(
                'class'=>'WebUser',
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
                'loginUrl'=>array('/user/login'),
    ),
        'authManager'=>array(
            'class'=>'RDbAuthManager',
            'connectionID'=>'db',
             'itemTable'=>'authitem',
        'itemChildTable'=>'authitemchild',
        'assignmentTable'=>'authassignment',
        'rightsTable'=>'rights',
            'defaultRoles'=>array('Authenticated', 'Guest'),
    ),
          'bootstrap' => array(
        'class' => 'bootstrap.components.BsApi',    ),


    // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format

    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
                'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules'=>array(
              'user/registration/<id:\w+>' => 'user/registration',
                                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),

    /*'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'sqlite:'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../data/testdrive.db',
    ),*/
    // uncomment the following to use a MySQL database

    'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=copy',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),

    'errorHandler'=>array(
        // use 'site/error' action to display errors
        'errorAction'=>'site/error',
    ),
    'log'=>array(
        'class'=>'CLogRouter',
        'routes'=>array(
            array(
                'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                'levels'=>'error, warning',
            ),
            // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
            /*
            array(
                'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
            ),
            */
        ),
    ),
),

// application-level parameters that can be accessed
// using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
'params'=>array(
    // this is used in contact page
    'adminEmail'=>'webmaster@example.com',
),
```

);

and this is my controller business

class BusinessController extends RController
{

```
public function filters()
{
    return array(
        'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
        'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
'rights',
                );
}

/**
 * Specifies the access control rules.
 * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
 * @return array access control rules
 */
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'actions'=>array('index','view'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
            'actions'=>array('create','update'),
            'users'=>array('@'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
            'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
            'users'=>array('admin'),
        ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}

/**
 * Displays a particular model.
 * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
 */
public function actionView($id)
{
    $this->render('view',array(
        'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
    ));
}

/**
 * Creates a new model.
 * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 */
public function actionCreate()
{

        $model=new Business;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Business']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Business'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}

/**
 * Updates a particular model.
 * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
 */
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Business']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Business'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}

/**
 * Deletes a particular model.
 * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
 * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
 */
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

    // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
    if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
        $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
}

/**
 * Lists all models.
 */
public function actionIndex()
{
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Business');
    $this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}

/**
 * Manages all models.
 */
public function actionAdmin()
{
    $model=new Business('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['Business']))
        $model->attributes=$_GET['Business'];

    $this->render('admin',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}

/**
 * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
 * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
 * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be loaded
 * @return Business the loaded model
 * @throws CHttpException
 */
public function loadModel($id)
{
    $model=Business::model()->findByPk($id);
    if($model===null)
        throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
    return $model;
}

/**
 * Performs the AJAX validation.
 * @param Business $model the model to be validated
 */
protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
{
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='business-form')
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

it is because of this mistake.the problem lies in the writing of the code, make sure you must write your code in config.main like this

```
'import' => array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
        'bootstrap.behaviors.*',
        'bootstrap.helpers.*',
        'bootstrap.widgets.*',
//add this code after the above code and thats it, a small stupid mistake may cost you 3 days of hard debugging.
        'application.modules.user.models.*',
        'application.modules.user.components.*',
        'application.modules.rights.*',
        'application.modules.rights.components.*'



    ),
```